# Possibility to remove the clickable link title in the ngb-panel from NgbAccordion in ng-Bootstrap

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using the [Accordion from ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/accordion/examples) in **Angular 2.x**. I am actually using three buttons to toggle the content of the three Accordion Panels as show in figure below.
[image: Panels and Buttons used to toggle]

Every time a user clicks on the button the respective panel toggles and the user can interact with it.

I wish to strictly use the buttons to interact with the Accordion and do not want the **Title Links** e.g. `Property Panel`, `Values Panel`, `Reference Panel` to be *Clickable* in order to provide a non-confusing User Interaction.

Is there a possibility to disable the feature?

Comment: Why not use simply ngbCollapse https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/collapse/examples?

Comment: I did start with it `ngbCollapse` but aesthetically Accordion looked better. In worst case I can go back to collapse. And also one benefit that collapse does not provide is `closeOthers` i.e. when one panel is open others can remain close.